# problem when try to make ajax request with django

Tags: python, django, ajax

i have a problem when make ajax request to the server to add product to the card using django and jquery,

this the URLs here:

```
path('add_to_cart/', cartView.add_to_cart, name="add_to_cart")
```

here the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    
    $('.addToCartBtn').click(function (e) {
    console.log("jjjj")
     e.preventDefault();
     var product_id = $(this).closest('.product_data').find('.prod_id').val()
     var product_qty = $(this).closest('.product_data').find('.qty-input').val()
     var token = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
console.log(token)
        console.log(product_id)
        console.log(product_qty)
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'add_to_cart',
        data: {
            'product_id' : product_id,
            'product_qty' : product_qty,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: token

        },
        success: function(res) {
            console.log(res.status)
            alertify.success(res.status)
        }
    })
})

});
```

and here is the view django code:

```
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from store.models import Product, Cart


def add_to_cart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            prod_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
            product_check = Product.objects.get(id=prod_id)
            if product_check:
                if Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, product_id=prod_id):
                    return JsonResponse({'status': 'Product Already in the Cart'})
                else:
                    prod_qty = int(request.POST.get('product_qty'))
                    if product_check.quantity >= prod_qty:
                        Cart.objects.create(user=request.user, product_id=prod_id, product_quantity=prod_qty)
                        return JsonResponse({'status': 'Product Added Successfully'})
                    else:
                        return JsonResponse({'status': "only" + str(product_check.quantity) + "is Available"})
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'status': 'No Such Product Found'})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'Login To Continue'})
    return redirect('/')
```

and here is the view.html when add to card button exist:

```
<section style="background-color: #eee;">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="container py-5 product_data">
            <div class="row justify-content-center mb-3">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xl-10">
                    <div class="card shadow-0 border rounded-3">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
                                    <div class="bg-image hover-zoom ripple rounded ripple-surface">
                                        <img src="{{ product.product_image.url }}"
                                             class="w-100"/>
                                        <a href="#!">
                                            <div class="hover-overlay">
                                                <div class="mask"
                                                     style="background-color: rgba(253, 253, 253, 0.15);"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                                    <h1>{{ product.name }}</h1>
                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                                        <div class="text-danger mb-1 me-2">
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                  <div class="container">
                                       <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-btn">

                                        <input type="hidden" value="{{ product.id }}" class="prod_id">
                                        <button type="button" class="quantity-left-minus btn btn-primary btn-number"
                                                data-type="minus" data-field="">
                                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </span>
                                            <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity"
                                                   class="form-control input-number qty-input" value="0" min="1" max="10">
                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button type="button" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-primary btn-number"
                                                data-type="plus" data-field="">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                   </div>
                                  </div>

                                    <div class="mt-1 mb-0 text-muted small">
                                        {{ product.description }}
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 border-sm-start-none border-start">
                                    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-1">
                                        <h4 class="mb-1 me-1">{{ product.selling_price }}</h4>
                                        <span class="text-danger"><s>{{ product.original_price }}</s></span>
                                    </div>
                                    {% if product.trending %}
                                    <h6 class="text-center badge bg-danger" style="font-size: 16px">Trending</h6>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    <div class="d-flex flex-column mt-4">
                                       {% if product.quantity > 0 %}
                                         <button class="addToCartBtn btn btn-primary btn-sm " type="button">Add To Cart</button>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm mt-2" type="button">
                                            Add to wishlist
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

this is the error message when I click on the button to make a ajax call:

```
ValueError: The view store.views.product_details didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
[03/May/2022 21:11:11] "POST /category/mobile/add_to_cart HTTP/1.1" 500 65574
```

Comment: You're calling product_details and it is not returning anything

Comment: @OsamaMohammed Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72104032/17562044) not worked?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is throwing error the view return `None` instead since you haven't redirected it inside the `if` condition where you are handling `POST` request.

Redirect it inside the `if` condition.

Try this:

```
def add_to_cart(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            prod_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
            product_check = Product.objects.get(id=prod_id)
            if product_check:
                if Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user.id, product_id=prod_id):
                    return JsonResponse({'status': 'Product Already in the Cart'})
                else:
                    prod_qty = int(request.POST.get('product_qty'))
                    if product_check.quantity >= prod_qty:
                        Cart.objects.create(user=request.user, product_id=prod_id, product_quantity=prod_qty)
                        return JsonResponse({'status': 'Product Added Successfully'})
                    else:
                        return JsonResponse({'status': "only" + str(product_check.quantity) + "is Available"})
            else:
                return JsonResponse({'status': 'No Such Product Found'})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'Login To Continue'})
        return redirect('/')
```